# Unable to load Symmetricds Web UI

Tags: database, database-replication, symmetricds

I'm trying to use symmetric-server-3.14.7. When I try to start the Web UI with bin/sym command, it stops on " [startup] - SymmetricWebServer - Joining the web server main thread " and when I open the browser it shows " HTTP ERROR 403 Forbidden ".

Did anyone else have this issue and know how to solve this?

p.s. I've added engines corp-000.properties, store-001.properties and store-002.properties from the samples folder to the engines folder but I still have the same issue. I'm using Windows 11 Professional.

[Starting WebUI in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVU6J.png)
[Browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd7rb.png)

Comment: Any error messages and stack traces in log files?

Comment: @BorisPavlović Actually no, nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no web interface for the open-source version of SymmetricDS. It uses HTTP to communicate data information. If you want a web interface, you can use SymmetricDS Pro, which is a commercial product.

Comment: There is actually a wesever starting up in log.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a webserver running in SymmetricDS. The webserver provides HTTP endpoints for the remote nodes to register and push/pull data to the server. The user interface, which is also hosted in that webserver, is only available in SymmetricDS Pro and a current license key.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).